# How add css attributes in button_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have next helper

```
= button_tag :type => "button", { "Add", :id => "poll-btn", :class => "btn-bg" }
```

Syntaxis is incorrect. How correct add css attributes(id, class) with type and content?  Sorry for very easy and stupid quation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= button_tag 'Add', type: 'button', id: 'poll-btn', class: 'btn-bg'
```